# I'm getting build errors when using MvxEventToCommand within a WP8 project

Tags: windows-phone-8, mvvmcross

I'm using the MvvmCross framework to create a windows phone 8 project.
In my WP8 project within the xaml I have the following:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers >
   <i:EventTrigger EventName="Tap">
      <Commands:MvxEventToCommand Command="{Binding OnItemTappedCommand}" />
   </i:EventTrigger >
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

My namespaces are as follows:

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
```

and

```
xmlns:Commands="clr-namespace:Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsPhone.Commands;assembly=Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsPhone"
```

When I attempt to build I get the error:

Cannot resolve dependency to assembly 'System.Windows.Interactivity, Version=3.8.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' because it has not been preloaded. When using the ReflectionOnly APIs, dependent assemblies must be pre-loaded or loaded on demand through the ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve event.

Looking in ILSpy I can see that Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsPhone.dll references this dll but I only have version 3.9.5.0 available in my assembly references list within my project.

I've tried adding an assembly redirect in my app.config but I think that's more for runtime resolution then for build errors.

What's the best way to resolve this issue?

Thanks

-- EDIT --

I've managed to resolve this issue by finding a WP7.1 version of the System.WindowsInteractive.dll which is version 3.8.5.0.  My project is definitely targeting the Windows 8.0 phone OS.

Could this be a problem with the Nuget packaging of MVVMCross?

Comment: Away from home. Can't answer properly. I know eventtocommand relies on interactivity from blend - but normally the ms sdk installs this... Will try to check more next week.

Comment: Thanks.  I have things working using that older version now but it would be nice to use the updated one.

The SDK did install System.Windows.Interactive it appears to be version 3.9.5.0 though.

Comment: The mvvmcross framework uses projects targeted to wp7.1 there's one project that as a reference to system.windows.interactivity. If your main project is targeting wp8, maybe there's a conflict somewhere... I've had this same issue, some time ago, but I'm using the mvvmcross projects directly, so I've just converted the WP7.1 projects to WP8. This is not the best approach but for me it worked. Maybe I'll change that in a near future.

Comment: That definitely seems to be the issue. Glad I'm not the only one.

Answer (score 3):

Just to answer this question since I came across this problem today...

I had a fresh install of Windows 8.1 and the Windows Phone 8 SDK. My sln would build but when MvvmCross resolved the plugins on start-up it would crash with a `ReflectionLoadTypeException` - the `LoaderExceptions` property contained a single entry - it was unable to find `System.Windows.Interactivity`, despite being referenced from the extensions list in the reference manager for the project.

The solution was to install the Windows Phone 7 SDK and grab the Windows Phone 7 version from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Expression\Blend\Windows Phone\v7.1\Libraries\System.Windows.Interactivity.dll`.

Comment: Yeah, I downgraded the dll in the end to get it to work.  Unfortunately this meant that I couldn't use some other ThirdParty assemblies as they referenced the newer version of System.Windows.Interactivity.  As @zleao pointed out it's because the MVVMCross projects target the WP7.1 versions of that dll.

Comment: Came across the same issue today. Solved it by copying MvxEventToCommand.cs into our WP8 solution and referencing it (which then builds against the correct System.Windows.Interactivity version) instead of the one from MvvmCross.